# JQuery/AJAX post checkbox array

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I have a Checkbox array check[] and I need to pass this via a JQuery Ajax request to another php file.  I would like the receiving php file to pick up the array as it would any other POST variable and the way it would without Ajax as $_POST['check'].

Do I need to use JQuery to parse this data into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ to create a url encoded string from your checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //when the form is submitted
  $("form").submit(function(e){
    //prevent the form from actually submitting.
    e.preventDefault();
    //put your PHP URL in here..
    var url = "postToThisURL";
    //create empty object
    var obj = {};
    //grab the checkboxes and put in arr
    var arr = $(this).serializeArray();
    //iterate over the array and change it into an object
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) obj[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
    //post the data to the server
    $.post(url, obj, function(r){
      //log the response when it is complete.
      console.log(r);
    });
  });
});
```